# How to handle StackTraceElement exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception

**I am getting UI : Exception in clickNewPurchase(): [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@52e6b75 exception.** 
But the thing is it is able to navigate next page. Below you can find the code. How can I avoid getting this exception and how can I identify where exactly I am getting this issue and what is causing this issue? Any help?

```
private void clickNewPurchase() throws Throwable {
    try {
        List<WebElement> listOfbuttons = createElements(newPurchase);
        for (WebElement element : listOfbuttons) {
            String value = element.getAttribute("value");
            if (value.equals("New Purchase") || value.equals("RePurchase")) {
                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver.get();
                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
                baseClass.logInfo("Clicked on New Purchase / RePurchase button on Start a Purchase page");
                waitforVisibilityOfElement(currentPage);
                break;
            }else if (value.equals("Retrieve")) {
                masterData.get().put("IncompletePurchase", "True");
                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver.get();
                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
                baseClass.logInfo("Clicked on Retrieve button on Start a Purchase page");
                waitforVisibilityOfElement(currentPage);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        softAssertFail("Exception in clickNewQuote(): " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()), ValidationType.UI);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
<br> <b>>></b> UI : Exception in clickNewPurchase(): [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@3bea26bc
at org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert.assertAll(SoftAssert.java:43)
at tests.P2Test.p2Test(P2Test.java:167)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

P2Test Line 167

```java
try {
    if (sam.getSoftAssert() != null)
        sam.getSoftAssert().assertAll();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Assert.fail("Problem in Soft assert: " + e.getCause());
}
```

Comment: when I even move e.printStackTrace(); to front softassertFail still getting same exception.

Comment: what if I replace getStackTrace with getMessage ?

Comment: P2Test line 167 is only doing assertAll

Comment: Why are you calling a TestNG method (`softAssertFail`) in non-testcase code?  That seems totally wrong.  Also `throws Throwable` and `catch Exception` and `e.printStackTrace()` in production code are a really bad idea.

Comment: *Finally `"How to handle StackTraceElement exception" `.*  - That's not an exception and it cannot be handled.  And `softAssertError` doesn't throw an exception either.  Your question does not make any sense.   You should explain ... in clear English ... what your code is trying to do, and what it actually does.  What is "this issue".

Answer (score 0):

You're asking several questions-

1. From the title- How to handle stack trace elements- I would say you don't- just let the exception bubble up, unless there's some logic you can fallback to when the exception happens.
2. "But the thing is it is able to navigate next page"- The way I read that is your users are not aware of a problem. That's because you're handling the exception and there is nothing to throw (that is assuming `softAssertFail` doesn't throw an exception)
3. "How can I avoid getting this exception" that we can't really tell- the root cause of your exception is all swalled up by that `Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace())` - I can't think of any good reason to do that- What's the intent behind this?
4. Where I'm confused a bit is the greater context of your question: It sounds like you're getting this as part of a unit test case? But you also mention user navigation.

I think you may get a better idea of what is happening if you take a step back and do not handle the exception (ie remove the `try..catch`), and take it from there.